# Using jQuery, selecting a Div by id, by choosing from dropdownlist and draw it inside another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**here's uncompleted script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#box1').hide();
           $('#box2').hide();
           $('#box3').hide();
           $("#thechoices").change(function(){
              if(this.value == 'all'){
                     $("#boxes").children().show();
                  }else{
                     $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
                  }
           });          
           $("#thechoices").change(); 
        });
</script>
```

---

And the HTML is:

```
<div id="SelectedBoxContainer">
    <!--Selected DivByID goes here-->
</div>


<!--Selected one of these Divs-->
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="box1"><p>Box 1 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box2"><p>Box 2 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box3"><p>Box 3 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box4"><p>Box 1 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box5"><p>Box 2 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box6"><p>Box 3 stuff…</p></div>
</div>
```

What i need is to use Dropdownlist to select a div from *div id="boxes"* and draw it inside *div id="SelectedBoxContainer"*,

How to achieve that? thanks in advance!

Comment: *draw it inside div*, do you mean, as in clone it into the other div? Or move it there?

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS, doesn't matter but if i could move it that will be great.

Comment: The else part could be like `else{
$("#SelectedBoxContainer").html($("#" + this.value).html());
                     $("#boxes").hide();
                  }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move the divs around using `.appendTo()`, but your HTML isn't currently well suited to maintaining that. I'd put a class on the `<div>`s that are being shown/hidden/moved so that you can track them easier:

```
<div id="boxes">
    <div id="box1" class="resultBox"><p>Box 1 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box2" class="resultBox"><p>Box 2 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box3" class="resultBox"><p>Box 3 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box4" class="resultBox"><p>Box 1 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box5" class="resultBox"><p>Box 2 stuff…</p></div>
    <div id="box6" class="resultBox"><p>Box 3 stuff…</p></div>
</div>
```

Now you can rewrite your change handler:

```
$("#thechoices").change(function(){
    if(this.value == 'all'){
        $(".resultBox").appendTo($("#SelectedBoxContainer")).show();
    }else{
        $(".resultBox:not(#" + this.value + ")").hide().appendTo($("#boxes"));
        $("#" + this.value).appendTo($("#SelectedBoxContainer")).show();
    }
});
```

The trick is that when there is only a single target element for .appendTo(), jQuery will move, rather than clone, elements that are already in the DOM.

Note that this solution will not preserve the order of the divs. Since it hides the ones that aren't selected, that will only be a problem when all are selected.

Comment: You just answer it thaks alot, but is there a way to clear the orginal div by using empty()?

Comment: @Ray - empty() would remove the content from the DOM; if you're moving not cloning, that means you risk losing the content permanently if you don't have some other reference to it. Pete's answer uses empty() with cloning, which is a safer way of doing that. Pete's answer is also order-preserving, while mine isn't

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to show and hide the divs if you are just wanting to show them in the `SelectedBoxContainer`, you can do something like this:

```
var selectBox = $('#SelectedBoxContainer')
selectBox.empty();

var clone = $("#" + this.value).clone();
clone.appendTo(selectBox);
clone.show();
```

Comment: On the other hand if you don't want them visible while unless they're selected, you can hide them all and then show the clones. Or even easier, use CSS rather than .hide() to hide the content of #boxes and leave Pete's answer unchanged.

Comment: you would put this inside the `$("#thechoices").change(function(){ //here });`

Answer (score 0):

assuming the value you are getting after change event is matchin the div id..

try this

```
$("#thechoices").change(function(){
          if(this.value == 'all'){
                 $("#boxes").children().show();
              }else{
                  $("#" + this.value).show().siblings().hide();
                  $('#SelectedBoxContainer').html($("#" + this.value).clone());
              }
       });
```